# mdadm raid doesn't mount

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm, array

I have a raid array defined in `/etc/mdadm.conf` like this:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 devices=/dev/sdb6,/dev/sdc6
ARRAY /dev/md1 devices=/dev/sdb7,/dev/sdc7
```

but when I try to mount them, I get this:

```
# mount /dev/md0 /mnt/media/
mount: special device /dev/md0 does not exist
# mount /dev/md1 /mnt/data
mount: special device /dev/md1 does not exist
```

`/proc/mdstat` meanwhile says:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md125 : inactive dm-6[0](S)
      238340224 blocks

md126 : inactive dm-5[0](S)
      244139648 blocks

md127 : inactive dm-3[0](S)
      390628416 blocks

unused devices: <none>
```

So I tried this:

```
# mount /dev/md126 /mnt/data
mount: /dev/md126: can't read superblock
# mount /dev/md125 /mnt/media
mount: /dev/md125: can't read superblock
```

The fs on the partions is `ext3` and when I specify the fs with `-t`, I get

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md126,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (could this be the IDE device where you in fact use
       ide-scsi so that sr0 or sda or so is needed?)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

How can I get my raid arrays mounted? It's worked before.

**EDIT 1**

```
# mdadm --detail --scan
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md/127_0: No such file or directory
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md/0_0: No such file or directory
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md/1_0: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 2**

```
# dmsetup ls
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid7    (252:6)
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid6    (252:5)
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid5    (252:4)
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid3    (252:3)
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid2    (252:2)
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid1    (252:1)
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid     (252:0)
# dmsetup table
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid7: 0 476680617 linear 252:0 1464854958
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid6: 0 488279484 linear 252:0 976575411
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid5: 0 11968362 linear 252:0 1941535638
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid3: 0 781257015 linear 252:0 195318270
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid2: 0 976928715 linear 252:0 976575285
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid1: 0 195318207 linear 252:0 63
isw_cabciecjfi_Raid: 0 1953519616 mirror core 2 131072 nosync 2 8:32 0 8:16 0 1 handle_errors
```

**EDIT 3**

```
# file -s -L /dev/mapper/*
/dev/mapper/control:              ERROR: cannot read `/dev/mapper/control' (Invalid argument)
/dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid:  x86 boot sector
/dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=a8d48d53-fd68-40d8-8dd5-3cecabad6e7a (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
/dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid3: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=3cb24366-b9c8-4e68-ad7b-22449668f047 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
/dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid5: Linux/i386 swap file (new style), version 1 (4K pages), size 1496044 pages, no label, UUID=f07e031f-368a-443e-a21c-77fa27adf795
/dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid6: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=0f0b401a-f238-4b20-9b2a-79cba56dd9d0 (large files)
/dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid7: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=b2d66029-eeb9-4e4a-952c-0a3bd0696159 (large files)
#
```

Also when I have one additional disk `/dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid` in my system - I tried to mount a partition but got:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid6 /mnt/media
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
```

I rebooted and confirmed that RAID is turned of in my `BIOS`.

```
I tried to force a mount which seems to allow me to mount but the content of the partition is inaccessible sio it still doesn't work as expected:
# mount -ft ext3 /dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid6 /mnt/media
# ls -l /mnt/media/
total 0
# mount -ft ext3 /dev/mapper/isw_cabciecjfi_Raid /mnt/data
# ls -l /mnt/data
total 0
```

**EDIT 4**

After executing suggested commands, I only get:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bc]6 /dev/sd[bc]7
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sd[bc]6: No such file or directory
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sd[bc]7: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT 5**

I got `/dev/md127` mounted now but `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1` are still not accessible:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bc]6 /dev/sd[bc]7
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sd[bc]6: No such file or directory
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sd[bc]7: No such file or directory



root@regDesktopHome:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md12[567]
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
root@regDesktopHome:~# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md127 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
root@regDesktopHome:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid1 dm-3[0]
      390628416 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md1 : inactive dm-6[0](S)
      238340224 blocks

md0 : inactive dm-5[0](S)
      244139648 blocks

unused devices: <none>
root@regDesktopHome:~# ls -l /dev/mapper
total 0
crw------- 1 root root  10, 236 Aug 13 22:43 control
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   0 Aug 13 22:43 isw_cabciecjfi_Raid
brw------- 1 root root 252,   1 Aug 13 22:43 isw_cabciecjfi_Raid1
brw------- 1 root root 252,   2 Aug 13 22:43 isw_cabciecjfi_Raid2
brw------- 1 root root 252,   3 Aug 13 22:43 isw_cabciecjfi_Raid3
brw------- 1 root root 252,   4 Aug 13 22:43 isw_cabciecjfi_Raid5
brw------- 1 root root 252,   5 Aug 13 22:43 isw_cabciecjfi_Raid6
brw------- 1 root root 252,   6 Aug 13 22:43 isw_cabciecjfi_Raid7
root@regDesktopHome:~# mdadm --examine
mdadm: No devices to examine
root@regDesktopHome:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid1 dm-3[0]
      390628416 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md1 : inactive dm-6[0](S)
      238340224 blocks

md0 : inactive dm-5[0](S)
      244139648 blocks

unused devices: <none>
root@regDesktopHome:~# mdadm --examine /dev/dm-[356]
/dev/dm-3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 124cd4a5:2965955f:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 18:50:36 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 390628416 (372.53 GiB 400.00 GB)
     Array Size : 390628416 (372.53 GiB 400.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 127

    Update Time : Sat May 31 18:52:12 2014
          State : active
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 23fe942e - correct
         Events : 167


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       35        0      active sync

   0     0       8       35        0      active sync
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync
/dev/dm-5:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 19:15:33 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
     Array Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri May  9 21:48:44 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : bfad9d61 - correct
         Events : 75007


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       38        0      active sync

   0     0       8       38        0      active sync
   1     1       8       22        1      active sync
/dev/dm-6:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  8 21:19:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
     Array Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1

    Update Time : Fri May  9 21:48:44 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 2a7a125f - correct
         Events : 3973383


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       39        0      active sync

   0     0       8       39        0      active sync
   1     1       8       23        1      active sync
root@regDesktopHome:~#
```

**EDIT 6**

I stopped them with `mdadm --stop /dev/md[01]` and confirmed that `/proc/mdstat` wouldn't show them anymore, then executed `mdadm --asseble --scan` and got

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 1 drives.
mdadm: /dev/md1 has been started with 2 drives.
```

but if I try to mount either of the arrays, I still get:

```
root@regDesktopHome:~# mount /dev/md1 /mnt/data
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

---

In the meantime, I've figured out that my superblocks seem to be damaged (PS I have confirmed with `tune2fs` and `fdisk` that I'm dealing with an `ext3` partition):

```
root@regDesktopHome:~# e2fsck /dev/md1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 59585077 blocks
The physical size of the device is 59585056 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>? yes
root@regDesktopHome:~# e2fsck /dev/md0
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 61034935 blocks
The physical size of the device is 61034912 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>? yes
```

But both partitions have some super blocks backed up:

```
root@regDesktopHome:~# mke2fs -n /dev/md0 mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem label= OS type: Linux Block size=4096 (log=2) Fragment
size=4096 (log=2) Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks 15261696
inodes, 61034912 blocks 3051745 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super
user First data block=0 Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296 1863
block groups 32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group 8192
inodes per group Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 265408, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872

root@regDesktopHome:~# mke2fs -n /dev/md1 mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem label= OS type: Linux Block size=4096 (log=2) Fragment
size=4096 (log=2) Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks 14901248
inodes, 59585056 blocks 2979252 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super
user First data block=0 Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296 1819
block groups 32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group 8192
inodes per group Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
```

What do you think, should I try to restore the backup on both arrays to `23887872`? I think I could do that with `e2fsck -b 23887872 /dev/md[01]` do you recommend giving this a shot? 
I don't necessarily want to try around with something I don't exactly know abd that might destroy the data on my disks... `man e2fsck` doesn't necessarily say it's dangerous but there might be another, saver way to fix the superblock...?

---

**AS A LAST UPDATE TO THE COMMUNITY**,

---

I used `resize2fs` to get my superblocks back in order and my drives mounted again! (`resize2fs /dev/md0` & `resize2fs /dev/md1` got my back  up!)
Long story but it finally worked out! And I learned a lot in terms of `mdadm` along the way! Thank you @IanMacintosh

Comment: Your `mdadm.conf` is odd. Normally it has `UUID=some:thing:ran:dom` instead of `devices=`. What's the output of `mdadm --detail --scan`?

Comment: Also those `md12[567]` you have are on device mapper devices. Try `dmsetup ls` or `dmsetup table` to see what they are, maybe something LVM related?

Comment: @frostschutz I don't understand what you mean by  "Your mdadm.conf is odd.", can you clarify please - See **EDIT 1** for output from `mdadm --detail --scan` - Thanks!

Comment: @frostschutz **EDIT 2** for the results of `dmsetup` - to be honest, I can not remember if they are on `LVM` or not, I set them up like 5 years ago or so and they always used to run fine - until I updated to Kubuntu 14.04 and my raid broke... that's where I'm at now...

Comment: Looks like fakeraid with `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. Try `file -s -L /dev/mapper/*` if there is anything of use.

Comment: @frostschutz The RAID setup in the `BIOS` wasn't recognized by Linux initially that's why I setup my raid with `mdadm` - do you think that might be the problem here? How did you find out about the `fakeraid`? Please see `/dev/mapper` output above in **EDIT 3**. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting dual problem. Glad it's sorted! Re the raid setup though I would look to ensure there is only 1 raid array per physical device if possible. I prefer to use LVM to subsequently 'partition' the /dev/mdX device. Also, don't forget to save your current working config to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf using mkconf to ensure it stays working :-)

Comment: @IanMacintosh is there a particular reason why you recommend to have only one partition per physical RAID device or is this your personal preference?

Comment: Use raid (mdadm) to make your array of disks redundant first, then use LVM to partition that space into volumes and then lay your filesystems onto the LVM volumes. ie, RAID is to make your disks redundant not to make volumes. LVM is to make volumes (it can RAID but not as well as mdadm). ie, my recommendation is to use each tool to its strength. YMMV :-)

Comment: @IanMacintosh fai enough! Thanks for your suggestion! I'll need to find a tool to merge my partitions first without losing my data. I think `parted` might be helpful for that, won't it?

Comment: Depends on if you're using LVM already or not. If you're using LVM you can move volumes from disk to disk trivially as long as you have the space available, and best of all, you don't even take them offline to do so. But we're getting too long on comments here!  I suggest a new question if you're looking for how to shuffle with LVM (hint: see `pvmove`). If they're not on LVM, then rsync is a good way to do it online (again need disk space). BUT you don't have to shuffle your data right now. You can file the recommendation away for next time you set up your PC and do it then, it's not critical.

Comment: You have saved my life with this article. Finally after restoring superblock from a backup my raid1 WD MyBook World disk came back to live and allowed to mount from /dev/mdX device.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your arrays are not properly started.  Remove them from your running config with this:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md12[567]
```

Now try using the autoscan and assemble feature.

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Assuming that works, save your config (assuming Debian derivative) with (and this will overwrite your config so we make a backup first):

```
mv /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf.old
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

You should be fixed for a reboot now, and it will auto assemble and start every time.

If not, give the output of:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bc]6 /dev/sd[bc]7
```

It'll be a bit long but shows *everything* you need to know about the arrays and the member disks of the arrays, their state, etc.

Just as an aside, it normally works better if you don't create multiple raid arrays on a disk (ie, /dev/sd[bc]6 and /dev/sd[bc]7) separately. Rather, create only one array, and you can then create partitions on your array if you must. LVM is a much better way to partition your array most of the time.

Comment: Hi @IanMacintosh, I added the results to **EDIT 4** above, Thank you for looking at them!

Comment: What happened with the stop command followed by the `mdadm --assemble --scan`? If your devices were at all discoverable then they should have come through that fully assembled and started. Can you add the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` after you have done the first two commands?

Comment: Can you also paste the output of `ls -l /dev/mapper` to that? You've already got the dmsetup ls output but the ls will help clarify and link the dm-3, 5 & 6 from your second paste. After that I can give you the proper device names for a complete `mdadm --examine`. If your layout is still the same as from the beginning of your post (cat /proc/mdstat) then also paste the output of `mdadm --examine /dev/dm-[356]`

Comment: Hi Ian, I've provided the output of all the above commands above under **EDIT 5** - Thanks!

Comment: Yay, I got `/dev/md127` mounted now but `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1` are still not accessible, as described in **EDIT5**

Comment: Hmm, your raid arrays changed since your first post. You must stop *all* the arrays *except* for /dev/md127. Type `mdadm --stop /dev/mdXXXXX` for all the other array until `cat /proc/mdstat` *only* shows /dev/md127. Then type `mdadm --assemble --scan`. That should start all your arrays correctly, except for /dev/md127 which is now out of sync and needs rebuilding, probably manually. Will tackle that later. I'll look at the raid details (--examine data) in the morning.

Comment: **EDIT 6** above provides some interesting further analasys, unsure if you can help me or if I rather open another thread as it doesn't necessarily look like my problem it's still `mdadm` related... Thanks for your insight!

Comment: I had a raid but it no longer would load, just like OP. 
Thanks to Ian Macintosh the RAID is now mounting fine AND with the original name. In trying I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.4 to 16.4; but the fix was the above. No idea how mdadm.conf got destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

This will fix it permanently:

```
# mdadm -Es > /etc/mdadm.conf
# dracut -H -f /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```